# Microsoft graph filtering on type isof('microsoft.graph.message') not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

While trying to get email messages via Microsoft Graph we are getting not only Messages but also EventMessages.  We would like to filter these out in the query by using

```
isof('microsoft.graph.message')
```

We are getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "RequestBroker--ParseUri",
        "message": "Cast or IsOf Function must have a type in its arguments.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "6ca66ac0-47d2-4742-b5d6-c8dcfe386408",
            "date": "2020-01-17T15:01:57"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there another way to filter out the EventMessages?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This support isn't available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter by the MessageClass using the singleValueExtendedProperties for pidTagMessageClass https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessageclass-canonical-property that should work okay eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/?$select=ReceivedDateTime,Sender,Subject&$Top=10&$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties%2fany(ep%3a+ep%2fid+eq+%27String+0x001a%27+and+ep%2fvalue+eq+%27IPM.Note%27)
```